# backbone and iterating through a collection but the results are not being appended to $(this.el)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am migrating a standard web app to backbone and today is the first day so assume I have made some really beginner error. I have the following View class which takes a collection. I am iterating through it and it returns what it's supposed based console.log'ging (commented as 'this works ok') it but it doesn't append anything (commented as 'this doesnt work'). Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong by this fragment?

```
var HomepagePositionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render:function(){
       var str="";
       this.collection.forEach(function(location){
         var hpsView=new HomepagePositionView({model:location});
         //hpView.render();
         console.log(hpsView.render().el); // this works ok
         //str+=hpView.el;
         $(this.el).append(hpsView.render().el);  // this doesn't work

       });
       //$(this.el).text(str);
       console.log(this.el); // just <div></div>
       return this;
    }
  });
```

thx for any help

**edit #1**

this is how I'm instantiating:

```
homepage_position: function(){
  console.log("within homepage_position");
  this.homepage_positions= new Locations();
  this.homepage_positions.url='/hex-jt/api-homepage-position';
  var str="";
  this.homepage_positions.fetch({success: function(data){
    var hpView= new HomepagePositionsView({ collection:data});
    hpView.render();
    console.log(hpView.el);
    //str+= $.html(hpView.el);
    $('#app').html(hpView.el);
  }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're iterating through your collection, ***this*** no longer refers to your view object, which you are using to reference your el. Try caching this outside the loop, assigning this to self, then referencing your el from self when you're appending the el from the rendered subview.

```
var self = this;

this.collection.forEach(function () {
    $(self.el).append(...)
});
```

Comment: great, that was it. Does the forEach start a new scope - is it because it's a function and creates a new reference to `this`?  Kinda confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show where you are initializing your new view ie:

```
new HomepagePositionsView({...})
```

My guess is you aren't providing an el to append to, so what is happening is that you are creating the html in your view correctly but your are not specifying an DOM element to attach it to. Just to be clear it should look something like this:

```
new HomepagePositionsView({collection: myCollection, el: $('#someElToAttachTo')})
```

You should use this.$el instead of $(this.el), since this.$el is a cached jQuery object. Also, if your Backbone library is up to date you can do

```
this.collection.each(function(){...})
```

which will delegate to underscore.js, which in turn whill delegate to the fastest option depending on the browser. Finally, I would consider looking at Marionette.js if you are going to do any serious work with Backbone, as it takes provides many nice features for building large js apps.

Comment: thx, I added my instantiation code, Let me look through what you said in your answer. I'm aware using hpView is REALLY REALLY bad practice. actually let me change that now. Marionette, let me get these basics down first :-)

Comment: Everything looks good. Check $('#app').html(hpView.el); The problem lies either in $('#app') not grabbing an element, or hpView.el is not producing any html.

Comment: Also a compact way of rendering something is new HomepagePositionsView({ collection:data, el:$('#app')}).render();

Comment: hmm... so I think it's the latter hpView.el not producing proper output but that's what I'm trying to figure out. thx

Comment: Ah, it's probably because 'this' in the context of the forEach is not the view. Either declare var self = this; outside the forEach and then do self.$el... or use this.collection.each(function(){...},this) and then 'this' will be the correct context